# How to fix ".. was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop" in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership

I have to iterate on keys, find the value in HashMap by key, possibly do some heavy computation in the found struct as a value (lazy => mutate the struct) and cached return it in Rust.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:25:26
   |
23 |     fn it(&mut self) -> Option<&Box<Calculation>> {
   |           - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
24 |         for key in vec!["1","2","3"] {
25 |             let result = self.find(&key.to_owned());
   |                          ^^^^ `*self` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
...
28 |                 return result
   |                        ------ returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
```

Here is the [code in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2145642bf0e9861b7cd13dfa243c77f6).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Calculation {
    value: Option<i32>
}

struct Struct {
    items: HashMap<String, Box<Calculation>> // cache
}

impl Struct {
    fn find(&mut self, key: &String) -> Option<&Box<Calculation>> {
        None // find, create, and/or calculate items
    }

    fn it(&mut self) -> Option<&Box<Calculation>> {
        for key in vec!["1","2","3"] {
            let result = self.find(&key.to_owned());
            if result.is_some() {
                return result
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

- I can't avoid the loop as I have to check multiple keys
- I have to make it mutable (`self` and the structure) as the possible calculation changes it

Any suggestion on how to change the design (as Rust forces to think in a bit different way that makes sense) or work around it?

PS. There are some other issues with the code, but let's split the problems and solve this one first.

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/3650362)

Comment: Help but still can't understand why it should not compile. Ok self is being borrowed till the function call self.find(...) ends, and even the lifetime of `result` ends before the next iteration. So "why" and how is "was mutably borrowed here in the **previous iteration** of the loop" is an error and what if it wasn't error, how can we wrongly use it. Even a brief explanation will help, this error confuses me :' )

Comment: This is a limitation of the current borrow checker. Polonius accepts it.

Comment: Polonius is the next version of the borrow checker, https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do caching with *exclusive* access. You can't treat Rust references like general-purpose pointers (BTW: `&String` and `&Box<T>` are double indirection, and very unidiomatic in Rust. Use `&str` or `&T` for temporary borrows).

`&mut self` means not just mutable, but *exclusive* and mutable, so your cache supports returning only one item, because the reference it returns has to keep `self` "locked" for as long as it exists.

You need to convince the borrow checker that the thing that `find` returns won't suddenly disappear next time you call it. Currently there's no such guarantee, because the interface doesn't stop you from calling e.g. `items.clear()` (borrow checker checks what function's interface allows, not what function actually does).

You can do that either by using `Rc`, or using a crate that implements [a memory pool/arena](https://lib.rs/memory-management).

```rust
struct Struct {
   items: HashMap<String, Rc<Calculation>>,
}

fn find(&mut self, key: &str) -> Rc<Calculation>
```

This way if you clone the `Rc`, it will live for as long as it needs, independently of the cache.

You can also make it nicer with interior mutability.

```rust
struct Struct {
   items: RefCell<HashMap<…
}
```

This will allow your memoizing `find` method to use a shared borrow instead of an exclusive one:

```rust
fn find(&self, key: &str) -> …
```

which is much easier to work with for the callers of the method.

Comment: In order to modify Calculation (`Rc::get_mut()`) Rc<Calculation> strong_count have to be = `0`, but it can be used somewhere. Basically this locks mutation until it's read or hold somewhere. So just using of `RC` does not help if i understand correctly (instead of compilation issue we have the same runtime issue)

Comment: If you need shared mutability (that causes cached entries to be mutated too), then use `Rc<RefCell<Calculation>>`.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not the cleanest way to do that, but it compiles. The idea is not to store the value found in a temporary result, to avoid aliasing: if you store the result, `self` is kept borrowed.

```
impl Struct {

    fn find(&mut self, key: &String) -> Option<&Box<Calculation>> {
        None
    }

    fn it(&mut self) -> Option<&Box<Calculation>> {
        for key in vec!["1","2","3"] {
            if self.find(&key.to_owned()).is_some() {
                return self.find(&key.to_owned());
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: that seems to be not good for performance: `find` is called twice. There should be a "proper way"

Comment: I agree with you, it could be better. On the other hand, for your specific case, `find` is not that expensive, since it is only a lookup in a hashtable, and you know that the value exists. If I understand correctly your intentions, the heavy calculation is done once anyway, so maybe this double call is quite small compared to that. I'll try to think of a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, and I found a workaround by turning the `for` loop into a `fold`, which convinced the compiler that `self` was not mutably borrowed twice.

It works without using interior mutability or duplicated function call; the only downside is that if the result was found early, it will not short-circuit but continue iterating until the end.

Before:

```
for key in vec!["1","2","3"] {
    let result = self.find(&key.to_owned());
      if result.is_some() {
          return result
      }
}
```

After:

```
vec!["1", "2,", "3"]
    .iter()
    .fold(None, |result, key| match result {
        Some(result) => Some(result),
        None => self.find(&key.to_string())
    })
```

Working playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92bc73e4bac556ce163e0790c7d3f154